# How to query keywords in a comment in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I havea table with a `string` column:

```
    text
I have two cars
I have a big house
```

I want to query from this table only records that has the word `cars`

**the expected output:**

```
I have two cars
```

I tried:

```
select text from tlb
where text in ('cars')
```

but it only returns exactly 'cars'

Postgresql V14

Comment: `where text in ('cars')` is the same as `where text = 'cars'` - why would you expect that to return a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIKE operator could help.

```
select * from tlb where lower(texts) like '%cars%';
```